# Encoding issue for generated source mapper in Mapstruct on IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8, mapstruct

I'm using Mapstruct for generating dto objects for my entities. I'm using IntelliJ on windows 10 in Turkish on my laptop. My Problem was following.

```
 @Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2016-09-05T16:36:08+0300",
    comments = "version: 1.0.0.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
public class VeininvoiceMapperImpl implements VeininvoiceMapper {

    private final LocalDateMapper localDateMapper = Mappers.getMapper( LocalDateMapper.class );
    private final BoxTypeMapper boxTypeMapper = Mappers.getMapper( BoxTypeMapper.class );
    private final InvoiceStatusCodeMapper ınvoiceStatusCodeMapper = Mappers.getMapper( InvoiceStatusCodeMapper.class );
    private final SenderLabelMapper senderLabelMapper = Mappers.getMapper( SenderLabelMapper.class );
    private final PostboxLabelMapper postboxLabelMapper = Mappers.getMapper( PostboxLabelMapper.class );
    private final VeinpartnerMapper veinpartnerMapper = Mappers.getMapper( VeinpartnerMapper.class );

    @Override
    public Invoice veininvoiceToDto(Veininvoice veininvoice) {
        if ( veininvoice == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Invoice ınvoice = new Invoice();

        ınvoice.setInvoiceStatusCode( ınvoiceStatusCodeMapper.statusToDto( veininvoice.getInvoicestatuscode() ) );
        ınvoice.setBoxType( boxTypeMapper.boxtypeToDto( veininvoice.getBoxtype() ) );
        ınvoice.setPartner( veinpartnerMapper.veinpartnerToDto( veininvoice.getVeinpartner() ) );
        ınvoice.setInvoiceNr( veininvoice.getInvoiceNr() );
        ınvoice.setIsarchive( veininvoice.getIsarchive() );
        ınvoice.setUblversionid( veininvoice.getUblversionid() );
        ınvoice.setCustomizationid( veininvoice.getCustomizationid() );
        ınvoice.setCopyindicator( veininvoice.getCopyindicator() );
        ınvoice.setIssuedate( localDateMapper.issueDateToCalendar( veininvoice.getIssuedate() ) );
        ınvoice.setIssuetime( veininvoice.getIssuetime() );
        ınvoice.setServicetypecode( veininvoice.getServicetypecode() );
        ınvoice.setNote( veininvoice.getNote() );
        ınvoice.setCurrencycode( veininvoice.getCurrencycode() );
        ınvoice.setLinecountnumeric( veininvoice.getLinecountnumeric() );
        ınvoice.setIsactive( veininvoice.getIsactive() );
        ınvoice.setSenderLabel( senderLabelMapper.senderLabeltoDto( veininvoice.getSenderLabel() ) );
        ınvoice.setPostboxLabel( postboxLabelMapper.postboxLabelToDto( veininvoice.getPostboxLabel() ) );
        ınvoice.setId( veininvoice.getId() );
        ınvoice.setUuid( veininvoice.getUuid() );

        return ınvoice;
    }
```

as you see, variable names created as ı instead i. And if i try to deploy or make module. it fails and all ı characters in class become '?' like following. .

```
  @Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2016-09-05T16:39:20+0300",
    comments = "version: 1.0.0.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
public class VeininvoiceMapperImpl implements VeininvoiceMapper {

    private final LocalDateMapper localDateMapper = Mappers.getMapper( LocalDateMapper.class );
    private final BoxTypeMapper boxTypeMapper = Mappers.getMapper( BoxTypeMapper.class );
    private final InvoiceStatusCodeMapper ?nvoiceStatusCodeMapper = Mappers.getMapper( InvoiceStatusCodeMapper.class );
    private final SenderLabelMapper senderLabelMapper = Mappers.getMapper( SenderLabelMapper.class );
    private final PostboxLabelMapper postboxLabelMapper = Mappers.getMapper( PostboxLabelMapper.class );
    private final VeinpartnerMapper veinpartnerMapper = Mappers.getMapper( VeinpartnerMapper.class );

    @Override
    public Invoice veininvoiceToDto(Veininvoice veininvoice) {
        if ( veininvoice == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Invoice ?nvoice = new Invoice();

        ?nvoice.setInvoiceStatusCode( ?nvoiceStatusCodeMapper.statusToDto( veininvoice.getInvoicestatuscode() ) );
        ?nvoice.setBoxType( boxTypeMapper.boxtypeToDto( veininvoice.getBoxtype() ) );
        ?nvoice.setPartner( veinpartnerMapper.veinpartnerToDto( veininvoice.getVeinpartner() ) );
```

i tried to set encoding for file and for whole project to UTF-8 ( settings -> File Encodings). But it didnt work.

Maven for the first scenario looks like this.

```
 ...
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      ...

<plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>

                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

then i changed the maven configuration to following. And i managed to generate mapper classes with i instead ı. But on make module it fails and all i characters in class changed to ?.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-J-Duser.language=en_us</arg>
                        <arg>-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <!--<proc>none</proc> &lt;!&ndash; disable annotation processing to avoid duplicating maven-processor-plugin output &ndash;&gt;-->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

more interestingly, in order to test it, i have created a sample project just with mapper dependencies and an Object and DTO (ITestObject). And i gave it to my colleague. He has exactly same version for Java and Intellij and also installed windows 10 Turkish on his laptop. We changed -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to -J-Dfile.encoding=windows-1254. he made module without any problems after Build Success. File has not been corrupted. just in case recompile module he had also corrupted Mapper file as me. But with same config i cant make module succesfully after build access in maven. I also tried to set MAVEN_OPTS

-`Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=TR -Duser.language=es -Duser.variant=Traditional_WIN`

But unfortunately it didnt work. I think, problem is somehow related to OS with IntelliJ. I'm using IDEA 2016.2.3, Maven 3.3.9. Does someone have an idea why its happens or what it can be related to ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I take it the original java sources were in Latin-3.

The editor and compiler must use the same encoding. The change to UTF-8 is advisable on principle, so let's see.

- Try it all out in a test project.
- Have an external editor to check the encoding like Notepad++ or JEdit.
- Change the encoding to UTF-8 (POM, possibly other places)
- Leave the IDE
- Check that the encoding did not get automagically converted to UTF-8
- Convert all sorces to UTF-8.
- Start the IDE
- Do a clean, build all.

And then it probably did not work.
The `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` for maven is the right property, but non needed

```
<encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
```

Is decisive. Check that `project.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8`.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quickly answer. But it didnt work.  I already checked it on Notepad++. Class has UTF-8 encoding. And i added already sourceEncoding and outputEncoding set to UTF-8 in properties tag and using them for encoding. But somehow generated i characters in mapper classes are changed to ? After make class or make module. I have been struggling for more than 6 hours for solve this. But no result..

Comment: The Preferences of the Editor are allright too? It must be the mapstruct processor. See http://mapstruct.org/news/page/3.html look for encoding

Comment: Yes i'm pretty sure. i checked it several times for UTF-8. Thanks for link. i tried compiler args given for gradle. But no result again. if i cant solve this problem today, i think i will rename dto and go on like this. :)